How to convert pem/p12 certificate to BKS format using C#
I have been searching for days for any solution to convert a certificate to BKS format using C# .NET. Have not found anything. All solutions use command line, but I should convert certs programatically without executing any external commands. Is there any example or guide on how to do it? Is it possible at all?

Have you tried just using the official BouncyCastle Nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle.Cryptography/#supportedframeworks-body-tab

I hope you aren't using BKS-v1 files, because they are catastrophically insecure.

This question is similar to: Is there a C# equivalent of Java's BouncyCastleStore?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I have to create BKS. Equivalent is not enough, unfortunately, because I am developing an internal certificate provider and clients can request certificates in any format.
